# How to create and load a configuration file in dxl

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a script which saves some files at a given location. It works fine but when I send this code to someone else, he has to change the paths in the code. It's not comfortable for someone who does not know what is in that code and for me to explain every time where and how the code should be changed.

I want to get this path in a variable which will be taken from the configuration file. So it will be easier for everyone to change just this config file and nothing in my code. But I have never done this before and could not find any information on how I can do this in the internet.

PS: I do not have any code and I ask about an ultimate solution but it is really difficult to find something good in the internet about dxl, especially since I'm new with that. Maybe someone of you already does that or has an idea how it could be done?

Comment: Are you referring to an include statement? The solution would depend on what / how / where you need that path for.

Answer (score 1):

DXL has a perm to read the complete context of a file into a variable: string readFile (string) (or Buffer readFile (string))

you can split the output by \n and then use regular expressions to find all lines that match the pattern
`^\s*([^;#].*)\s*=\s*(.*)\s*$`
(i.e. key = value - where comment lines start with ; or #)

But in DOORS I prefer using DOORS modules as configuration modules. Object Heading can be the key, Object Text can be the value.
Hardcode the full name of the configuration module into your DXL file and the user can modify the behaviour of the application.
The advantage over a file is that you need not make assumptions on where the config file is to be stored on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your situation. You are going to need to be a little more specific about what you mean by "they need to change the paths in the code". What are these paths to? Are they DOORS module paths, are they paths to local/network files, or are the something else entirely?

Like user3329561 said, you COULD use a DOORS module as a configuration file. I wouldn't recommend it though, simply because that is not what DOORS modules were designed for. DOORS is fully capable of reading system files in one line at a time as well as all at once, but I can't recommend that option either until I know what types of paths you want to load and why.

I suspect that there is a better solution for your problem that will present itself once more information is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I needed to specify the path of my configuration file used in my **dxl script**.

I solved this issue passing the directory path as a parameter to DOORS.exe as follow:

```
"...\DOORS\9.3\bin\doors.exe" -dxl "string myVar = \"Hello Word\"
```

then in my dxl script, the variable myVar is a global variable.